# Make an onClick event before an onSubmit

Tags: javascript, html

I want to execute the `pergunta1` function the before form submits.

**HTML code :**

```
<form id="myform2" action="send_mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="beforeSubmit(this)">
   <input type="image" name="" id="Image1final"src="Imagens/R2.jpg" value="R1" border="0" onclick="pergunta1(this)" style="width:160px;height:160px;margin: 0 auto;display: none;" alt="" />
   <input type="image" name="" id="Image2final"src="Imagens/R8.jpg" value="R2" border="0" onclick="pergunta1(this)" style="width:160px;height:160px;margin: 0 auto;display: none;" alt="" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript code :**

```
function pergunta1(element) {

    if (element.getAttribute("value") == "R1") {
        res1 = "N1_1"
    } else if (element.getAttribute("value") == "R2") {
        res1 = "N1_2"
    }
    document.getElementById('Image1final').src = 'Imagens/R1.jpg'
    document.getElementById('Image2final').src = 'Imagens/R2.jpg'
    $("#Image1final").attr('value', 'N3_1');
    $("#Image2final").attr('value', 'N3_2');
    $("#Image1final").attr('onclick', 'pergunta2(this)');
    $("#Image2final").attr('onclick', 'pergunta2(this)');

}

function pergunta2(element) {
    cartafinal2 = element.getAttribute("value")
}

function beforeSubmit(element) {

    if (cartafinal2 == 'N3_1') {
        document.getElementById("subjectfinal").value = "Resultado do teste : 1";
    } else if (cartafinal2 == 'N3_2') {
        document.getElementById("subjectfinal").value = "Resultado do teste : 2";
    }
}
```

Is there any way that i can execute `pergunta2` first then execute `beforesubmit`, or anyway to insert the result of the `pergunta1`(N3_1 or N3_2) on the `beforesubmit`?

Comment: can you please explain what are you doing in pergunta1() function and where is your pergunta2() is used

Comment: in the pergunta1 im seeing wich image the user clicks and saving the result, then im changing the atributes of the images so that when i click in it again i can save another value, pergunta1() transforms the image onclick on to pergunta2()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is call `beforeSubmit` before the forms submit, you don't really need a `pergunta2` function.

You can just change the onclick attribute of your images so that `beforeSubmit` is called.

In beforeSubmit, you can retrieve the value of the clicked element, the same way you were doing it in `pergunta2`.

And then, using `document.getElementById("myform2").submit()`, you can submit your form at the end of the `beforeSubmit` function.

In the Snippet below, I commented the submit of the form and added a `subjectfinal` text field so you can test if it does what you want it to do.

```js
function pergunta1(element) {

    if (element.getAttribute("value") == "R1") {
        res1 = "N1_1"
    } else if (element.getAttribute("value") == "R2") {
        res1 = "N1_2"
    }
    document.getElementById('Image1final').src = 'Imagens/R1.jpg'
    document.getElementById('Image2final').src = 'Imagens/R2.jpg'
    $("#Image1final").attr('value', 'N3_1');
    $("#Image2final").attr('value', 'N3_2');
    $("#Image1final").attr('onclick', 'beforeSubmit(this)');
    $("#Image2final").attr('onclick', 'beforeSubmit(this)');
}

function beforeSubmit(element) {
    var cartafinal2 = element.getAttribute("value");
    
    if (cartafinal2 == 'N3_1') {
        document.getElementById("subjectfinal").value = "Resultado do teste : 1";
    } else if (cartafinal2 == 'N3_2') {
        document.getElementById("subjectfinal").value = "Resultado do teste : 2";
    }
    
    // Uncomment the line below to submit the form
    // document.getElementById("myform2").submit();    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform2" method="post">
   <input type="button" name="" id="Image1final" value="R1" border="0" onclick="pergunta1(this)" style="width:160px;height:160px;margin: 0 auto;" alt="" />
   <input type="button" name="" id="Image2final" value="R2" border="0" onclick="pergunta1(this)" style="width:160px;height:160px;margin: 0 auto;" alt="" />
   <input type="text" id="subjectfinal" />
</form>
```

Comment: `jQuery` was not mentioned neither in your post or OP's tags.

Comment: It worked thank you so much i had been stuck with this problem for 2 days